# ios: how to detect if a custom url scheme link failed?

Tags: javascript, ios, url-scheme, custom-url

I have an HTML page containing a link to a custom URL scheme, displayed on iPhone .e.g
myapp://localhost/

Assuming the user clicks it, but there is no app that can respond to this scheme, how do I catch this in javascript (that the link cannot be opened)?

tnx

Comment: Just because you rephrased it, doesn't make it any different: [how do I detect if window.location failed?]. Unless you are no longer talking about Javascript, in which case it should not be tagged as such. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404148/how-do-i-detect-if-window-location-failed)

Comment: @sagimann Are you using a `UIWebView` by any chance to display this html page?

Comment: See also:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964515/launching-app-or-app-store-from-safari

Answer (score 0):

Yes that can be done using webview delegate not using Javascript.

Similar question [How to handle app URLs in a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299403/how-to-handle-app-urls-in-a-uiwebview)

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)wv shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

// Determine if we want the system to handle it.
NSURL *url = request.URL;
if (![url.scheme isEqual:@"http"] && ![url.scheme isEqual:@"https"]) {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:url]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: OP asked for JavaScript.

Comment: @MarcusAdams : sorry for my mistake. answer modified

Comment: feels like the answer was not modified and this still isn't js...