# JavaScript: How to trigger function before and after downloading file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to toggle fade in and fade effect before and after the file was downloaded.

However, I was unable to check that the file download was completed or not before the `fn_fadeOutWaiting()` triggered.

I found the source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404148/how-do-i-detect-if-window-location-failed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download) but it did not help for my case.

Here's my JS code is just like this:

```
fn_fadeInWaiting(); 
document.location = "/Employee/Data?Type=CSV";
fn_fadeOutWaiting();
```

If the downloaded file size (`*.csv`) is small, the `fn_fadeInWaiting()` and `fn_fadeOut()` triggered at right time. However, if downloaded file size (`*.csv`) is a bit larger, the `fn_fadeOutWaiting()` was triggered even if the file was not yet downloaded.

How can I trigger `fn_fadeInWaiting()` and `fn_fadeOutWaiting()` correctly for the downloaded file? Thanks.

Comment: If the cookie approach isn't working I doubt there is any other approach that you can use

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks. I tried using `$.ajax()` `beforeSend()` and `success()` as  well but not help solved.

Comment: You can use an xhr request to download the file, check [this link](http://www.alexhadik.com/blog/2016/7/7/l8ztp8kr5lbctf5qns4l8t3646npqh) and then just check for the xhr response.

Comment: @chŝdk, following the link above, it works fine, however I would like skip giving file name manually here `a.download = 'myFile.pdf';` because I already config to name file automatically by giving the current date and time as the file name. So, can I skip this step above? Thanks.

Comment: @HouyNarun Yes of course, you can skip it, it's just used ofor the name of the download, you can set it tha way you want.